# Laravel 5 socket.io event message not displaying

Tags: node.js, sockets, laravel-5.1

I am implementing socket.io with redis and nodejs. I have done with event and data is coming to the node server, but i am not receiving that data on my laravel 5 blade page.

**Efforts**

```
**blade page for receiving**
<script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
        socket.on("test-channel:App\\Events\\MyEvent", function(message){
            // increase the power everytime we load test route
            console.log(message.data);
        });
</script>
```

Above code which is running on client side and not displaying data.

```
socket.js file

var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('redis');
var redis = Redis.createClient();

redis.subscribe('test-channel', function(err, count) {
    // console.log(err,count);
});
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

Above code which is running on server side and displaying data in terminal.

I don't understand where i am doing wrong. Please friend help me.

Comment: try to log incomming data on client side like
 console.log(message) 

NOT console.log(message.data)

Comment: @Mandy, I am facing the same issue. Did you solve this issue?